# How Can I Make An Area A Clickable Link?

Tags: html, css

I have a slideshow on my main homepage, and on the bottom of it, it's showing text.

I'd like the text, when hovered over, to change color to red, and to be able to be clicked, redirecting to a given link.

My code is as follows:

```
<div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</div>
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 450px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div data-p="218.75">
        <img data-u="image" src="images/slides/slide1.jpg" />
        <div style="position:absolute;top:370px;left:379px;width:500px;height:70px;z-index:0;font-family:Comic Sans MS;font-size:72px;color:#000000;line-height:70px;text-align:center;">Rationale</div>
    </div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<a href="url">text</a>` surely it can't be that simple...

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe's answer should work if your question is what I think it is. You can then use the [`:hover` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) to cause the link to become red when hovered over. It looks like you could also take a look at some CSS/Web Dev tutorials and move your CSS to a separate file. This will make everything more readable and people will be happier.

Comment: Adam's answer should suffice. Also, asking this... I'm assuming that you're a beginner with HTML, am I right? Otherwise, this will almost be considered as a troll question or something. Sorry if it sounds rude.

Comment: @FlameDenise Yes I am a beginner. Sorry if I made a troll worthy question, but I'm in grade 9 trying to make a site from scratch for my Geography project. I came here because this is where I normally find my answers, but I couldn't find one to this (eventually found a YouTube video). It doesn't sound rude at all, I know I'm a beginner, and I'll refrain from posting more questions like this before browsing a little more. Thanks for at least warning me :)

Comment: I hope I didn't discourage you, though. I used to be a beginner, too, and this site has been of great help to me back then. But you're right on "browsing a little more" before posting. That will keep you away from "harmful" responses. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically wrap any HTML element in the `<a>` tag. It then becomes clickable, and you can style it accordingly.

Alternatively, you can use the following CSS to make an element look like a link:

```
#myElement:hover {
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

You can then handle the `on click` with javascript. I hope that helps!